# Reconnect USB Modem every 12 hours

Tags: command-line, modem, 4g

I'm planning on having a 4G LTE USB Modem plugged into a server computer at home. I will then go somewhere else. I'm afraid it will disconnect, and if it does not work I would have to go home to fix it.

Is there a possibility to automatically remount / reconnect USB 4G Modem with a command every 12 hours?

It's a ZTE MF821D Modem, which means, it will connect to internet just by plug out and in.

Comment: To run a task at scheduled times, use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto). This isn't the best solution: it would be better to reconnect if the connection is dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that very easily , while you are creating the connection for Mobile broadband ,look at the 1st TAB[ General ]  there you can have the option as Automatically connect to this network when it is available .

so you even because of network problem you got disconnected your connection , it will reconnect again after sometime when network is available. so you can automate it very easily.[image]

Comment: Okay, but I dont need reconnect, thanks anyway, but Im aware it bugs often, eth1 dissapear, network closes, etc etc, I need to restart USB......

Comment: @Marcus ok along with the  answer I gave you ,restart your network manager and modem manager for 12 hours once. you can create a bash script for that and then by using cron you can automate the action.\

Comment: nop, its buggy USB modem, when I start computer it doesnt even start: I have to replug it. Sometimes it just disconnect. I want to play it safe, so I use: eject /dev/sr0, and wait 10 seconds, it will reconnect. Thanks for answer.